# Run Windows application as a current user or admin

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess, pywinauto

I'm trying to call Windows application (exe file) using Python (from Jupyter). The problem is, looks like, the application starts under another user, because all the user settings in that application are reset. Or, maybe this happening because the exe file is prevented from accessing required .ini file? The second is even more likely.
I tried each way to run the application, that I could find: os, subprocess, pywinauto, ShellExecuteEx. Nothing worked for me so far (I'm just starting to work with Python). Any thoughts on this?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Tasks manager?

Comment: alexchvrches, what do you mean? I'm trying run windows application from python code. Like this: 
filepath = 'textfile.txt'
import os
os.startfile(filepath)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't set the working directory.

This way app starts properly:

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\\Folder\\Subfolder')
os.system("app.exe")
```